# How to increase an integer number in `animate()` on each click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

How can I increase an integer number in `animate()` on each click?

For instance,

html,

```
<ul class="items-thread">
    <li class="item-thread">1</li>
    <li class="item-thread">2</li>
    <li class="item-thread">3</li>
    <li class="item-thread">4</li>
    <li class="item-thread">5</li>
    <li class="item-thread">6</li>
    <li class="item-thread">6</li>
    <li class="item-thread">7</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="more">more</a>
```

jquery,

```
$('.more').click(function(){
   $('.items-thread').animate({scrollTop:50}, 500);
   return false;
});
```

When I first click the button the element of `.items-thread` will be scrolled up `50px`, and when I click the button second time, it should be scrolled up `100px` and so on.

Comment: Can you post the CSS that goes with this? Is the `height` of `items-thread` limited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable, and increase its value on each click:

```
var scrollAmount = 50;
$('.more').click(function(){
    $('.items-thread').animate({scrollTop:scrollAmount}, 500);
    scrollAmount += 50;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

just use "+="

see this fiddle it adds 50 px margin-left on each click
http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/eKkZ4/

```
$('.more').click(function(){
   $('.items-thread').animate({marginLeft: '+=50px'}, 500);
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it.

```
$('.more').click((function(){
   var nScrollTop = 0;

   var animate = function () {
       nScrollTop += 50;
        $('.items-thread').animate({scrollTop: nScrollTop}, 500);
        return false;
   };

   return animate;   
})());
```